# How to make the h1 tag responsive to the background image (along with the background, the h1 tags shrinks & expand)

Tags: html, css

I have a background image in the `jumbotron` along with `h1` tags. As I resize the image, the `h1` tags do not resize, and overlap with the image in the background

```css
.jumbotron h1 {
  font-size: 45px;
}
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url("header.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 48px;
  padding-right: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- Jumbotron Header -->
  <div>
    <header class="jumbotron">
      <h1> Hello, how May I help you.</h1>
      <h1>Happy to help you<br>
       <img src="prime.png" class="img-responsive" alt="flower">
 </header>
 <div> 
</div>
```

Comment: As you resize the image? You mean while resizing the window ? Or are you using javascript to make your image resizable?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use javascript to shrink the font-size with the jumbotron.

If you are currently resizing the whole window to shrink the image, then you can just add the following:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {

    var h1 = document.getElementById("jumbo-h1");  //I made up an id for simplicity
    var width = document.getElementsByClassName("jumbotron")[0].offsetWidth;

    if (width > 600) {
       h1.style['font-size'] = "45px";
    } else if (width > 400 && width <= 600) {
       h1.style['font-size'] = "35px";
    } else {
       h1.style['font-size'] = "25px";
    }
}
```

if you are using jQuery, this becomes much cleaner:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
    var $h1 = $(".jumbotron h1");         //note that ID is not needed
    var width = $(".jumbotron").width();
    if (width > 600) {
        $h1.css({"font-size": "45px"});
    } else is (width > 400 && width <= 600) {
        $h1.css({"font-size": "35px"});
    } else {
        $h1.css({"font-size": "25px"});
    }
});
```

Obviously, play with the sizes/cutoff points to your hearts content to get the look you are after.

If you are resizing the jumbotron in other ways, simply move the code in the handler I provided into its own function and call that when needed (while also passing a reference to the window resize handler)

Answer (score 0):

I have two demos on Codepen that explore the concept of scaling text.

http://codepen.io/denmch/pen/MYZqXB

http://codepen.io/denmch/pen/EaGMYZ/

You can check the CSS and play with the concept on your own, but the basic idea is to calculate the font size using a combination of normal measures (em, rem, px…) and `vw` (viewport width-based measurement), which will produce a proportional text size that responds to the viewport. Here's an example:

```
h1 {
  font-size: calc(1rem + 3.5vw);
}
```

This idea has also been [explored by Mike Riethmuller](http://madebymike.com.au/writing/fluid-type-calc-examples) who has done a lot of great work and even apparently has videos on the subject.

It's considered experimental, but you should be good everywhere but Opera Mini.

Comment: I should add that you can see the scaling by resizing your browser window or comparing in multiple devices.

Comment: This will work if the window is resized, but will do nothing when programmatically resizing the jumbotron. Worth mentioning.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for all the help.